# iPhone Push Notification

Tags: ios4

hai I've 3 months of exp in I phone Programming.  Now
I am looking to use the Push Notification in my app.  Is there any way to do this.

Comment: Very tempted to answer just "Yes." Please make your question more specific.

Answer (score 3):

No, it's completely impossible and all mentions you've heard of it up until this point are lies designed to spread fear amongst the populace.

Additionally, it certainly isn't discussed in some detail in a document called "[Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html)".

Answer (score 0):

Implementing push notifications in your app really isn't very difficult. Most of the heavy lifting is done on the server side.

Urban Airship has a guide that will show you how to implement it using their service.

http://urbanairship.com/developers/